# Installing/building git-svn for RHEL 6

Tags: git, git-svn, rhel

I do not have access to the RHEL6 repo, so what wouold be the best approach to building and/or installing the git-svn tool on RedHat Enterprise Linux 6?

---

Managed to install git & git-svn 1.7.9 by uninstall the existing one (yum erase git) and make installing the latest one from source. Worked on 64-bit too.

Comment: Simple `yum install git-svn` worked for me. (1.8.2.1-1.el5                            epel-el5-x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to rebuild locally (ie in a directory within your home directory) everything:

- `git` and its dependencies
- `svn` and its dependencies
- `perl` and `ruby` (used by `git-svn` script)

You can try my [GitHub project compileEverything](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything):
(it will download and compile for you all the necessary sources: no configuration required)

```
cd ~
bash # (you need a bash session)
# set your http_proxy/https_proxy if needed
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/tarball/master
tar xpvf master
cd compil*
./maken-env.sh -title=test
# wait 4 hours
source .bashrc -force # special bash with all the right local path
```

`git` and `git-svn` will then work.

Comment: The compile-everything did not work (too many errors to list), will try to do it manually as indicated

Comment: @Nick, too many error, but I am interesting to have a look at your logs.

Comment: Finally found a way to share the log! http://www.fileuploadz.com/uploads/89f263551727d8c6f578e8a5692d7911.txt

Comment: @Nick: sorry I didn't get back to you for this error. Did you manage to compile everything in the end?

Comment: Seems so -- no hassles. There appears to be no prebuilt git-svn package on any RHEL 6 x64 repository. So building everything git from src was the only option. 10x