# git-svn package not found for RHEL.6 linux server

Tags: git, git-svn, yum, rhel6

I am doing the command `yum install git-svn` and I am getting the error message `No package git-svn available`.

This is an internal RHEL.6 linux server. When my company built the RHEL.5 linux boxes, we had the git-svn repo put on their by default. However, now it is not on RHEL.6 by default :(

What I have tried:

1. Plenty of [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=yum%20install%20git-svn%20package%20not%20found&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). I have tried everything on page 1.
2. [Installing/building git-svn for RHEL 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653531/installing-building-git-svn-for-rhel-6)
3. `yum install url` from [rpm find](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=git-svn) but I don't see a valid url

Is there a url I can pull this from using `yum`?

Any more options that I do not know about?

Server information:

`$ git --version
git version 1.7.1`

`$ rpm -q git
git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64`

```
$ yum repolist

Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
repo id repo name status
rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter RHEL6 Server Datace 16167
rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-epel RHEL6 Server Datace 22013
rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-hpsa RHEL6 Server Datace 101
rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-pe-3-8-2 RHEL6 Server Datace 65
rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-puppet-pe-agent-3-8-2 RHEL6 Server Datace 24
rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-spacewalk-client RHEL6 Server Datace 22
rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-company-tools RHEL6 Server Datace 150
rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-tools RHEL6 Server Datace 184
rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-zero-day RHEL6 Server Datace
```

Just to show what happens when I do `git svn`:

```
$ git svn
git: 'svn' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
    fsck
    show
```

Comment: The `git-svn` package is part of the RHEL and CentOS 6 base repositories. Are you sure you have them configured correctly? Because it should be there. What version of `git` do you have installed currently? (`git --version` and `rpm -q git`)

Comment: I did not build the server. It was already here when I got here. I did add the info you want though in the post.

Comment: Then assuming the repositories are configured correctly and complete you should be able to `yum install git-svn` correctly. What does `yum repolist` output?

Comment: `yum repolist` has been added above

Comment: Ah, I always forget RH chunks things up into channels. I have no idea what channel git-svn would be in. It might be worth seeing what other channels are available and which of then has the package as I still believe it must be there.

Comment: FWIW, on a RHEL 6.3 box I just checked, it's in `rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6`. You seem to have a different family of repos (datacenter), but I don't see an `optional` flavor, in any case.

Comment: @DanLowe Okay, thank you! I found this https://access.redhat.com/solutions/57504 which should help me add the channel.

Comment: On RedHat 7.2 make sure you enable rhel-7-workstation-optional-rpms. Replace workstation with server or whatever type you have installed.